Colors in node wrangler preview appear faded instead of solid
While using the node wrangler viewer node in the shader editor, I notice the colors are fading to white when they should be solid. Is it a problem with the node setup or the blender software itself? I am using Blender 4.2.1 LTS.


How it looks. The plane has been scaled up a little to show the effect more clearly.

How it should look.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kreQfdcC1_4

Hello, you're using Eevee versus the tutorial uses Cycles. Also make sure you didn't modify the view transform in the render settings. BTW this has most likely nothing to do with node wrangler, when you CTRL + click on a socket it just connects it to the material output as an emission shader

Changing the view transform settings from AgX to Standard fixed the issue. Thank you.
